# Find this limit $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $a_0 = \sqrt5$, $a_{n+1} = 2a_n^2-1$. Define $b_n :=2^na_0a_1...a_{n-1}$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 2$.

I can show that this limit exists by showing that the sequence is contractive, after which I have no clue how to find its value. Could someone point me in the right direction? The limit sort of makes sense because both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are more or less doubling in value each time, with the former one 'step' ahead of the latter

Comment: does it converges to $2$ ?? ,i got a different answer

Comment: I believe it does; managed to derive it after obtaining a hint from someone. Care to share how you got your different answer?

Answer (score 2):

We have with $a_n=\cosh(u_n)$, $u_{n+1}=2u_n$ giving $u_n=2^n u_0$. So $a_n=\cosh(2^n u_0)$ yielding

$$b_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}2a_k=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}2\cosh(2^k u_0)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\sinh(2^{k+1} u_0)}{\sinh(2^{k} u_0)}=\frac{\sinh(2^{n} u_0)}{\sinh(u_0)}.$$

It follows that $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sinh(u_0)\cosh(2^n u_0)}{\sinh(2^n u_0)}=\coth(2^n u_0)\sinh(u_0)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sinh(u_0)=\sqrt{a_0^2-1}.$$